# Configuring python interpreter PyCharm 2020.1 WSL2

Tags: pycharm, interpreter, wsl-2

I am trying to configure Python interpreter in PyCharm 2020.1 through WSL. I added my `wsl.exe` to `wsl.distributions.xml`, but I cant activate Python inside WSL. Getting error as in the screenshot. `python3` is installed in this Ubuntu distribution & also `miniconda`. All working good from `bash`.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are taking will work if you launch PyCharm from a directory within WSL. This means you will have to install PyCharm for Linux, and launch it from Linux using a window manager like X Windows (which requires setup) or VNC (which requires setup). That type of setup is non-trivial and out of scope for this question.

[PyCharm 2021.1 was *just* released](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2021/04/pycharm-2021-1/), and it makes working with WSL much better, rather like how VSCode does. With this new release, you can launch PyCharm from Windows, which is much simpler.